# Yammer Export zip file with sample data

Tags: export, yammer

I don't have access to Yammer export feature and interested in exported data from a yammer internal network for developing a custom application to parse and format/load data into different application. I have found the schema of the files on many sites but did not find any sample data.

Appreciate if some one can please share the export zip file from Yammer (sample site). I am primarily interested in Messages.csv, files, Pages.csv and Pages.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export the data from your own network, for this you must have the network admin rights.

Or if you just want to some sample data to create the application you can follow these sites which have sample data in power pivot you can export this data also.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richard_dizeregas_blog/archive/2014/04/09/yammer-analytics-with-excel-and-power-bi.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

Or if you be a little specific about your requirement.

Regards
Piyush

Comment: Hello Piyush, Thank you for your response. Appreciate it. I was not able to find the export zip file with contents on the site you have mentioned in your response. My Requirement: I need the zip file with exported Yammer content (with some good examples of all content (messages, files, pages etc) so that I can develop my program using the sample files. Thank you. If you have an export with zip file and you can share it. please send me the link to it.